# Does omitting await keyword once in the call stack break the asynchronous behavior of the whole stack?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous-programming, async

Call stack may contain several methods returning `Task`. If all of them are decorated with `async`, the flow of execution is quite simple. However, what if one of them is not `await`ed - are other method calls from that method executed asynchronously or not?

Here's an example:

If I have

```
async Task A()
{
    ...
    await B();
    ...
}
```

and if I call `A();` and not `await (A);` - will `await B();` be awaited?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .net the `async await` keywords are an extension of the Task Parallel Library.  When you do not `await` an `async` method it is almost equivalent to calling `Task.Run(()=>A())`

(There are some gotchas regarding UI threads or other single threaded applications here as with out `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, when creating the task, the awaited code will try to pick up on the same thread context.  If you are awaiting from a background worker thread context then await and `Task.Run()` are running in the same context.  If you are on the UI thread then the context of `Task.Run()` and the awaited context are different.)

In your example A() would start, return control at `await B()` and then the code calling `A()` would continue while `A()` was waiting for `B()` to complete.

A simple example would be the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting main");

    A();

    Console.WriteLine("Finished Main");

    //dont end before A() finishes.
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task A()
{
    Console.WriteLine("starting A");

    await B();

    Console.WriteLine("Finishing a");
}

static async Task B()
{
    //Add a delay before the Console.WriteLine
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    Console.WriteLine("starting B");

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    Console.WriteLine("Finishing b");
}
```

When the main method calls `A()` execution is serial until the `await B()`.  After `A()` calls await, control is returned to main which then finishes.  At this point `A()` is still out there running "Fire and Forget", which is bad in the case of a console program so we need to make sure that the main thread does not complete before `A()` finishes.  If we don't have the `Console.ReadLine();` the program will end after the call to `await` in `A()`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is accurate. I could have *sworn* that you only get fire and forget behavior with async void. For tasks that aren't awaited, aren't they simply run synchronously? (Please, I could be wrong, someone correct me if I am.)

Comment: @RubberDuck You get fire and forget from any non awaited task.  When you spin off multiple async methods you can then call await on `Task.WhenAll` to wait for all of them to finish (IE: Downloading multiple independent files in parallel).  If there is no await, then the files will still download but nothing will wait on them.  `async void` is a special case where you CAN NOT `await` but nothing says you have to await a method returning a task.

Comment: Okay. Yeah @WindRaven, it looks like you're right about that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh965065.aspx

Comment: 'Task.Run(()=>A())' isn't completely accurate. Task.Run runs the task on a separate thread, whereas just firing A() and forgetting about it, still runs it on the main thread. This can be a pretty important factor in cases where the UI does something after a task reaches a specific point in code. Arguably this is a design flaw, if your code relies on other code you can't await. But regardless, this could be a problem

Comment: Omitting `await` is certainly _not_ equivalent to `Task.Run(...)`. The latter uses a separate thread. "Do not try and use a thread. That's unnecessary. Instead, only try to realize the truth... There is no thread." Ah, I'll let Stephen Cleary explain it: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: This `Task.Run` equivalence is definitely wrong and should be improved here. Otherwise this answer contains a fact that could mislead future readers.